# Page not aligning properly when browser is restored down

Tags: visualforce

I am having trouble with the alignment of the page when I restore down the window. The page actually looks pretty good when my browser is in maximized mode.
Here is the sample code

```
<apex:outputText value="This sentence needs to be at the right corner of the page and the style I used is below" 
 style="font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;margin-left:575px;"/>
```

Comment: Please don't just pick a few tags, but try to find one or more tags with a direct relation to the subject of your question.  I've left the visualforce tag as this is is the nearest related, but if your questions is purely about CSS, it is technically off topic. If there is a direct relation and correlation to your css problem and it being on an VF page, it may help if you  share that with us by updating your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to use the css properties `position:absolute`, `top` and `right`:

```
<style>
.myBlock {
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid #6FEC79;
    background-color: #FFF;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: -102px 19px 0 0;
}
</style>

<apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="myBlock">
    <apex:outputText value="This is my text!" />
</apex:outputPanel>
```

After that the layer will be positioned to the top right corner of the page. Note that it is not "absolute" top right corner of the whole page, only the content area. You need to use margin to move the layer above the content arey (for example to the navigation block):

[image]